# CSS: What's causing this weird alignment?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have these inline-block elements with a set height and width and overflow:hidden. On chrome, it lines up nicely, but in an older webkit browser, it does this:

[image]

```
.item{
  display:inline-block;
  height:72px;
  width:144px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:left;
}
```

If I change them from overflow:hidden to overflow:scroll, they all line up (and overflow: auto makes them all line up except the ones not long enough to need scrollbars)

It almost seems like it's hiding the overflow by just making it invisible but still saving that space. Is that what's causing this?

Comment: Try to add `vertical-alighn: top;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `vertical-align: top` rule to `.item`, as inline-block elements will align via `baseline` (text bottom aligned) by default.

Comment: I would have expected that to line them up but still leave the goofy spacing, but it worked! Thank you.